# Responsive onclick dropdown Drupal 7 Omega 3

Tags: jquery, css, drupal-7

I'm playing with Omega 3 Subtheme [Drupal 7]. I wanted to have pure CSS responsive navigation which I think I managed to do. However now I think it would be nice to have it working `onclick` rather than on `hover`. So my research have taken me to jQuery and I'm not too comfortable with jQuery so I thought maybe that is a good time to ask some questions before I go the wrong way.

All my code is [in this Codepen](https://codepen.io/sebastiankijora/full/ggxMLP/).

The JavaScript I managed to get together:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var submenu=$(this).find("ul");
        $('li > ul').not(submenu).hide();
        submenu.toggle();
        $(this).children("ul.menu").toggleClass( "hover" );
    });
});
```

I feel it is pretty close but still I think `hover` is affecting the menu somehow. Not sure if I should remove all `hover` CSS as I think of it as a fallback, but maybe it is not necessary anymore.

Also the missing feature is hide the menu `onclick` outside of it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

After another few hours of guessing the correct jQuery here is my current code, inspired by [Philip Walton](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").find("ul").hide();
    $(".dropdown").children("ul").addClass("hover");
    $(".dropdown").click(function () {
        var submenu=$(this).find("ul");
        $('li.dropdown ul').not(submenu).hide();
        submenu.toggle();
    });
 });
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
    // Hide the menus.
    $(".dropdown").find("ul").hide();
  }
});
```

In terms of functions it is now doing what I wanted, still not sure if that is the easiest and cleanest approach.

Final solution, with "toggle" + added, still probably the code can be simplified.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").children("a").append("<span>+</span>");
    $('.dropdown > a > span').attr('title', '');
    $(".dropdown").find("ul").hide();
    $(".dropdown").children("ul").addClass("hover");
    $(".dropdown > a > span").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var submenu=$(this).parents(".dropdown").find("ul");
        $('li.dropdown ul').not(submenu).hide();
        submenu.toggle();
        $(".dropdown > a > span").not(this).removeClass("open-cross");
        $(this).toggleClass("open-cross");          
    });
 });
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
    // Hide the menus.
    $(".dropdown").find("ul").hide();
    $(".dropdown > a > span").removeClass("open-cross");
  }
});
```

Live version available at Codepen, link above.

Comment: Please add your html and css. RE: missing feature is hide the menu onclick outside of it -- do you mean that currently when you click a menu item the menu remains in a drop-down state?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @EmmaEarlKent please let me clarify in points:  1. When you go to my Codepen link you will see that all menu items are reacting to hover - that is CSS

Comment: 2. Afer clicking on Menu 1 the links are no longer reacting to hover - that is what I want but  3. Clicking Menu 1 again makes this one item react to hover whilst Items 2 and 3 are not reacting  4.Now you can click Menu 2 then Menu 3 and then Menu 1 and you will see the expected reaction (only hide on click outside missing) but that is not constant behaviour as when you click any item again the hover is working again.

Comment: Hi Sebastian Kijora - The only hover state I see is that the background color of Menu 1, Menu 2, Menu 3 and individual menu items changes on hover. Please clarify what you want the hover state to do, if anything.

Comment: @EmmaEarlKent thank you for the reply. I think I managed to get the result I wanted, at least in Codepen. You can check it at the Codepen link. I still have the problem in Drupal as it is not closing on click outside the menu, you can check it here http://kijora.com/sandbox